# How to use CASE plus JOIN plus GROUP BY into a single MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, case

```
SELECT B. * , SC.cate_name, (
CASE WHEN special_offer_type =  'Fixed Value'
THEN B.price - special_offer
WHEN special_offer_type =  'Discount %'
THEN B.price * ( 1 - special_offer / 100.0 ) 
ELSE B.price
END
) AS final_price
FROM book B
JOIN setting_category SC ON B.cate_id = SC.cate_id
```

Used above coding `CASE` and `JOIN`, I added 2 fields `cate_name` and `final_price` at `ideal_result_table` *(THX Gordon Linoff)*

Now I would like to calculate 2 more fields called `avg_rate` and `count_comment` at `ideal_result_table`, how can I do that?

User AAA and BBB added rating to the book 001, so `avg_rate`of book 001 is (4+5)/2 = 4.5 = 5

User CCC added rating to the book 002, so `avg_rate` of book 002 is 2

User XXX and YYY added comment to the book 001, so `count_comment` of book 001 = 2

```
book
-----------------------------------------------------------                     
isbn   cate_id   price   special_offer   special_offer_type
001    1         125     5               Fixed Value
002    1         90      30              Discount %
003    2         150     50              Fixed Value

setting_category
--------------------                            
cate_id   cate_name
1         Fiction
2         Dictionary

book_rating                             
------------------------------------------
user   dateadd      timeadd    isbn   rate
AAA    2014/03/20   15:00:00   001     4
BBB    2014/03/21   15:00:00   001     5
CCC    2014/03/22   15:00:00   002     2

book_comment
----------------------------------------------
user    dateadd      timeadd    isbn   comment
XXX     2014/03/20   16:00:00   001    good
YYY     2014/03/21   16:00:00   001    great

ideal_result_table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
isbn   cate_id   price   special_offer   special_offer_type   cate_name    final_price   avg_rate   count_comment
001    1         125     5               Fixed Value          Fiction      120           5          2
002    1         90      30              Discount %           Fiction      63            2          0
003    2         150     50              Fixed Value          Dictionary   100           0          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

`SELECT B.*,SC.cate_name,(
    CASE WHEN special_offer_type ='Fixed Value'
    THEN B.price - special_offer
    WHEN special_offer_type =  'Discount %'
    THEN B.price * ( 1 - special_offer / 100.0 ) 
    ELSE B.price
    END
    ) AS final_price,
    IFNULL(xx.avg_rate,'0'),
    IFNULL(yy.count_comment,'0')
    FROM book B JOIN setting_category SC ON B.cate_id = SC.cate_id 
    LEFT JOIN (select a.isbn,sum(a.rate)/count(a.rate) as avg_rate 
    from book_rating a 
    group by a.isbn) as xx on b.isbn = xx.isbn 
    LEFT JOIN (select c.isbn,count(*) as count_comment from book_comment c 
    group by c.isbn) as yy on b.isbn = yy.isbn`

CMIIW

EDITED..

Comment: The output result should be output all the records in table `book`.

However, the statement can only show the records when `count_comment` > 0.

I.E. the result only show record isbn 001. The isbn 002 and isbn 003 cannot be showed.

Comment: edited.. i'm sorry use left join :D and ifnull command.. so the null value become to 0..

Comment: output is based on book table and other table can be null.. so use left join table to join table based on book table.. and ifnull to change value if there is null result :D